# How to convert "[1,2,3]" to [1,2,3] in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to convert `"[1,2,3]"` to `[1,2,3]`.

I searched but didn't find any methods in the String class that will help me.

Comment: The normal way would be `"[1, 2, 3]".delete('[]').split(',').map(&:to_i)
 #=> [1, 2, 3]` or `"[1,2,3]"[1..-2].split(',').map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's a humble bit of JSON. Why are you opening it up like a walnut with a hammer? For a more lax approach might want to use `scan(/\d+/)` which does a good enough job.

Comment: @tadman, yes, `scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)` is better, but I would say loading JSON to do the job is like opening it up like a walnut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's a JSON nut meant for a JSON nut-cracker!

Comment: @tadman, have you ever tried moving that JSON nut-cracker out of the shed? It takes two burly men!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. It's important to show your attempt to solve this. Did you research it? If not, why? If so, why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, show us the smallest version that demonstrates the problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code to solve the problem for you, which is off-topic. Why is your array stringified? See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"
also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can parse it as JSON:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse "[1,2,3]"
#=> [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Wouldn't the best course be to find out _why_ the OP is getting a stringified array first?

Comment: @theTinMan it's not an unreasonable way to serialize an array to a string, so I answered the question directly. I think there could be a separate question from the OP on alternative serialization methods for an array, if that's what they were interested in.